# Tcl: Is parameter evaluation guaranteed to be left-to-right?

Tags: tcl

I have a Tcl program where I often find expressions of the following kind:

```
proc func {} {...}
...
lappend arr([set v [func]]) $v
```

The intended meaning of the last line is

```
set v [func]
lappend arr($v) $v
```

It obviously works. What I would like to know: Does it work "by accident", or does Tcl guarantee, that the first parameter passed to lappend is evaluated before the second?

Comment: It's a strict guarantee. It's also guaranteed in expressions; everything has a defined evaluation order (and if you find anything that violates that, it's a bug and should be reported as such).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl is always evaluated from left to right as you can read on the [documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M31), I quote the part:

> Substitutions take place from left to right, and each substitution is evaluated completely before attempting to evaluate the next. Thus, a sequence like:
>
> ```
> set y [set x 0][incr x][incr x]
> ```
>
> will always set the variable y to the value, 012.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with Jerry. Adding some flavor in it.

Tcl commands are evaluated in two steps :  *parsing* & *execution*.

- First the Tcl interpreter parses the command string into words, performing substitutions along the way.
- Then a command procedure processes the words to produce a result string. Each command has a separate command procedure.

[image]

Let us consider the following code.

```
%set input "The cat in the hat"
The cat in the hat
%string match "*at in*" $input
1
```

In the parsing step the Tcl interpreter applies the rules described in this chapter to divide the command up into words and perform substitutions.

*Parsing* is done in exactly the same way for every command. During the parsing step the Tcl interpreter does not apply any meaning to the values of the words. Tcl just performs a set of simple string operations such as replacing the characters `$a` with the string stored in variable a. Tcl does not know or care whether a or the resulting word is a number or the name of a widget or anything else.

In the *execution* step meaning is applied to the words of the command. Tcl treats the first word as a command name, checking to see if the command is defined and locating a command procedure to carry out its function. If the command is defined then the Tcl interpreter invokes its command procedure, passing all of the words of the command to the command procedure. The command procedure is free to interpret the words in any way that it pleases, and different commands apply very different meanings to their arguments.

Major rule to remember here

> 1. Tcl parses a command and makes substitutions in a single pass from left to right. Each character is scanned exactly once.
> 2. At most a single layer of substitution occurs for each character; the result of one substitution is not scanned for further
>      substitutions.

Reference : [Tcl and the Tk Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133633X)